# C# thread life of timer callback

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Just learning C# multi-threading basics and trying to understand what happens to the Threading.Timer thread in a callback in the following scenario.

This C# app that starts a Timer with a callback that does the following:

1. logs some info
2. uses Net.HttpWebRequest to query a REST server
3. logs more info

The timer interval is pretty quick (500 milliseconds).
When the query fails (because I unplug the network cable while running), I see the logs from #1 and know it will take some time but eventually I expect to see the matching logs from #3. Instead it's as if the thread (I believe from the thread pool) just dies. Not always. Just most of the time.

And when I re-connect the network, the queries succeed and I always see the logs from #3.

The callback step #2 is the following code:

```
private bool sendPostToServer(string url, string postCommand, out int tCnt)
{
    bool success = false;
    tCnt = 0;
    string newUrl = url + postCommand;
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(newUrl) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    byte[] postByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length;

    System.IO.Stream dataStream = null;
    try
    {
        dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {       
        String errMsg = String.Format("FAILED to connect to REST Server!");

        if (!this.errorDialogWasDisplayed)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Dialogs.CustomMsgBox.CustomMessageBox.Show(errMsg, "",
            System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Error)),
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
        }
    }

    if (dataStream != null)
    {
        dataStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        try  // try-A
        {
            System.Net.WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            try // try-B
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (Int32.TryParse(responseFromServer, out tCnt))
                {
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("ERROR - sendPostToServer - tryparse failed");
                }
                reader.Close();

            } // end of try-B
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR - sendPostToServer - StreamReader failed");
            }

            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }

            if (dataStream != null)
            {
                dataStream.Close();
            }

        } // end of try-A
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ERROR - sendPostToServer - GetResponse failed"); // or GetResponseStream failed
        }                
    } // end of if (dataStream != null)

    return success;
}
```

So why does the thread not complete and finish logging of step #3, when the task takes a while?

Thanks

---

### EDIT

Per request here is the Timer code. Not much to show though.

```
this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(getCurrentCount, null, 0L, pollingInterval);
```

callback:

```
private void getCurrentCount(object obj)
{
    if (sendPostToServer(this.serverUrlNPort, LinkCounter.postCount, out this.currentCount))
    {
        // do stuff with currentCount
    }
}
```

Comment: Network timeouts are quite long, 45 seconds or more.  You probably just didn't wait long enough.  Only showing connection failures in your UI but not transfer failures can't help much either.

Comment: The method returns false if any failure occurs. My log statements (removed for brevity) indicated the failures only happened on the connection call `GetRequestStream`. Which makes sense seeing how I pulled out the cable.  I waited quite some time and my debugging printouts are numbered. As if the threads just "disappeared".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans was right.
Did another test and reconnected the cable before I reached 250 threads (read somewhere on SO that 250 was a limit). Then waited for several minutes and searched my logs. Each thread did eventually return.
My bad. (  ; •ー_一 •)

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.timers.timer(v=vs.100).aspx

If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

Are you setting the SynchronizingObject on the timer?

Comment: You are talking about the completely wrong Timer class.